# Getting an TypeError when using datetime module

Tags: python

I want to print the **hour, minutes, seconds** given by the user through an input. However, it is appearing an unexpected error when I implement `time()`.

Here's my code:

```
from datetime import time

def main():
    departure_time = input("What is your departure time (hours, minutes, seconds)?")
    departure = time(departure_time)
    print(departure)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's the error that is appearing **(example of entering 12 hours, 50 min, 15 sec)**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jpvig\Desktop\Projeto Enes\home1.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\jpvig\Desktop\Projeto Enes\home1.py", line 7, in main
    departure = time(departure_time)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Well, `time('12 hours, 50 min, 15 sec')` is invalid input to `time`. The `time` constructor accepts separate numbers and nothing else: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time

Comment: You are not converting the inputted string into ints.

Comment: You should have 3 imput one for the hours, one for the minute and one for the seconds and convert each of them to an int

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
from datetime import time

    def main():  
        h, m, s = input("What is your departure time (hours, minutes, seconds)? ").split()
        
        departure = time(int(h),int(m),int(s))
    
        print(departure)
        
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Give the input is this way

```
What is your departure time (hours, minutes, seconds)? 22 11 33
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, time class takes int as parameters. You've passed string in them. That's the reason you're getting ValueError. Change them to int and then pass them to time class object. Your code:

```
from datetime import time
def main():
    departure_time = input("What is your departure time (hours, minutes, seconds)?")
    b=[int(x) for x in departure_time.split()]
    departure = time(b[0],b[1],b[2])
    print(departure)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support multiple different formats of user input, such as any of the following cases:

- `12 hours, 50 minutes, 31 sec`
- `1 hours 15 seconds`
- `12h50m15s`
- `30sec`
- `12:50:15`
- `52,31`

Then you can use a Regex such as below:

```
(?:(\d+)[ ]*[h,:][a-z,: ]*)?(?:(\d+)[ ]*[m,:][a-z,: ]*)?(?:(\d+)[ ]*s?[a-z]*)?
```

Here's a link if you want to test it out: [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/F6psex/2)

---

Below is a sample Python implementaiton, to demonstrate the parsing of the possible inputs that might be entered by the user.

```py
import re
from datetime import time


H_M_S_REGEX = re.compile(r'(?:(\d+)[ ]*[h,:][a-z,: ]*)?(?:(\d+)[ ]*[m,:][a-z,: ]*)?(?:(\d+)[ ]*s?[a-z]*)?')


inputs = """\
12 hours, 50 min, 15 sec
1 hr 15 minutes 0 seconds
12h50m15s
12,50,15
21,31
23h,31m
2h
1h 20m 15s
20m
30sec
12hr:2min:15s
12:50:15
"""

for user_input in inputs.splitlines():
    h_m_s_tuple = H_M_S_REGEX.match(user_input)

    h_m_s = [int(x) if x is not None else 0 for x in h_m_s_tuple.groups()]
    parsed_time = time(*h_m_s)
    print(parsed_time)
```

Out:

```
12:50:15
01:15:00
12:50:15
12:50:15
21:00:31
23:31:00
02:00:00
01:20:15
00:20:00
00:00:30
12:02:15
12:50:15
```